# if value = 3 show input and add required attribute

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select id='form'><option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option></select>
    <input id='input' style='display:none'>
    <input type='submit'>
```

I'm trying to make  that if `#form = 3`, the `#input` will be show and it will also add required on it. Am I missing something?

```
$("#input").change(function()
 {
var confirm = $("#form");
if (confirm == 3){
$('#input').prop("required", true) && $('#input').show();
}
 }
```

Comment: `var confirm = $("#form").val();` `if (confirm == 3){`

Comment: @Igor thank you that solved everything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the event listener 'change' to `#form` because that is the element that is changing.

Also need to get the `val()` of the selection made

```
$("#form").change(function() {
    var confirm = $(this).val();
    if (confirm == 3) {        
        $('#input').prop("required", true).show();
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ab30nrdc/1/)**

Optionally, hide input if not 3 (if they change selection)

```
$("#form").change(function() {
    var confirm = $(this).val();
    if (confirm == 3) {        
        $('#input').prop("required", true).show();
    } else {
        $('#input').hide();    
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ab30nrdc/2/)**

Answer (score 4):

A couple things:

Two equals signs for a boolean comparison `==` (one is for assignment).

$("#form") is just going to return a Jquery object representing the DOM element. Most likely, you want the value contained in that element: $("#form").val();

```
$("#input").change(function() {
    var confirm = $("#form").val();
    if (confirm == 3){
       $('#input').prop("required", true) && $('#input').show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be forgot val() function and values in option.
It will be like

```
<select id='form'><option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option></select>
    <input id='input' style='display:none'>
    <input type='submit'>

    $("#input").change(function()
 {
var confirm = $("#form").val();;
if (confirm == 3){
$('#input').prop("required", true) && $('#input').show();
}
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please see Igor's comment above. Needs `==` in `if`

Comment: Yep i forgot that too. Ty :) Edited.

Comment: You don't need to add value options if they are the same as the element's text value.

(See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element)